# Manually change the shipment state in spree from backorder to shipped in spree admin UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, spree

Using spree to run a store. I want to use the check payment method since I want to receive payments once the customer has received the goods. Is there a way to change the shipment state in the admin UI from backorder to shipped once I release the shipment from the store(noticed in most cases payment comes first before the order is shipped but in my case I want to ship before receiving the payment). Is there a way to manually trigger the shipped state in the admin UI?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Spree uses the state-machine gem to handle payments and shipments and there is a lot that goes on behind the scene every time an order is updated. You could write your own extension to accomplish this, but experience has taught me that hacking the Spree state machine can have disastrous results if you're not careful, so make sure you build a good test suite if you decide to go that route.